# Slow Localhost - Problems with CMS

Tags: content-management-system, localhost, wamp

I have windows 8.1 with wamp 2.5 64bits..

when I had windows 7 with wamp 64bits (2.5) was very fast with Wordpress..

Now, with windows 8.1 wordpress or zencart in very slow..

Whats up with my wamp?

I've also tested with xampp and the results is the same.

Can you help me with this problem?

Best reagrds

Comment: This question is a little out of scope for StackOverflow as it's not really a programming question. It might be more suitable for SuperUser, as sister site of StackOverflow on the StackExchange network.

Comment: hmmm... :( sorry.. but ajax  is a problem of programming.. and wordpress and all CMS use ajax...

Comment: All computers use metal as well, but that doesn't make this a metallurgy question :) It's just a hint on how to get better answers that solve your problem, I hope you aren't offended :)

Comment: Ook Martijin.. thanks for your help... :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try this, it has been known to fixes this kind of speed issue.

Edit your httpd.conf file, using the menu links on wampmanager i.e.

```
wampmanager -> Apache -> httpd.conf
```

Add these 2 lines just before the comment line `# Supplemental configuration`

```
AcceptFilter http none
AcceptFilter https none

# Supplemental configuration
```